# I'm getting an error of "Could not find a declaration file for module 'react'"

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import React from 'react' and getting an error..

The setup I'm using was created with the standard npx create-react-app.

The error I'm seeing is from VS Code.

import React from 'react';

Could not find a declaration file for module 'react'. '/home/darryl/dev/learn-react/node_modules/react/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare m

I'd expect to not receive this error and for my app to load in the browser.

I haven't tried the suggest fix yet 'npm install @types/react' as I should not be receiving this error anyway and I was hoping to gain further understanding of why I am seeing this before making changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `npm install --save react` .

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Answer (score 2):

Running the suggested fix 'npm install @types/react' seems to fix the issue. But this seems to be an issue with the create-react-app installer then?

Answer (score 0):

Is react well listed in "dependencies" in your package.json ?

Have you try to import it with require (Vanilla Style instead of ES6)?